# Error when trying to call rest api sometimes

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

Sometimes when i try to call my rest api it does throw an exception (when i use jmeter to test) log and sometimes it works perfectly, this is my code:
*this api calls an oracle database.

```
@GetMapping(value = BASE_URI + "/myApi")
public List<MyXObjects> getMyApiObject() {
    return this.dirRepository.findMyXObjects();
}
```

and this is the error stack (this log is been written when i was testing using jmeter) :

> 2019-02-01 16:10:04 ERROR ErrorPageFilter:213 - Cannot forward to error page for request [/api/pub/myApi] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:356)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:808)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:713)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:391)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:369)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:2033)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.writeNumber(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:876)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.NumberSerializers$LongSerializer.serialize(NumberSerializers.java:179)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:112)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:704)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:690)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:112)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:416)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1425)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:951)
>           at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:292)
>           at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:106)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:231)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:174)
>           at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)

Comment: I think you calling direct query from repository, DB call take some time to execute query's

Comment: i've extended time to 5min for timeout and proxytimeout in my tomcat conf

Comment: You can try with limit query, Then we will see the result

Comment: you mean using pageable ? i think its not necessary, results are like 40 objects and each have nested objects

Comment: the problem is db query take too much time that's why sometimes it's working sometimes it's not working

Comment: is there a way to extend timeout socket ? in apache or tomcat ot spring boot configuration ?

Comment: extend timeout is not a recommend way

Comment: whet is the best way then ?

Comment: try with pagination

Comment: but i have to return the whole result at once for angular

Comment: any solutions ?...

Comment: take cache and use it